I am trying to hit a PATCH API in C# and getting http 400 bad request error. However same API is working and returning 200 response in ReadyAPI tool
I am trying to hit a PATCH API using C# and getting a http 400 bad request error. However, the same API is working fine and returning http 200 responses in Ready API tool. I tried all the ways from Stack Overflow and not sure what I am missing.
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Net.Http.Json;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
 
string apiUrl = "https://tfs.ups.com/tfs/UpsProd/P04S_SPPS/_apis/testplan/Plans/5150238/Suites/5716385/TestPoint?includePointDetails=true&returnIdentityRef=true";
string username = "******";
string password = "******";

var credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
var handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = credentials };

WebClient client1 = new WebClient();
client1.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
 
using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
{
    try
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(apiUrl);
 
        string json = "[{\"id\":3490616,\"results\":{\"outcome\":2}}]"
        
        Console.WriteLine(json);
        var method = new HttpMethod("PATCH");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
  
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/json");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("api-version", "6.1-preview.2");

        byte[] messageBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
        var content = new ByteArrayContent(messageBytes);
        content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
             
        var response = client.PatchAsync(apiUrl, content).Result;

        Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Console.Write("Success");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
    }
}


400 status denotes a bad API request. Try logging the response content; it might provide more insights.

Snippet to log the response content:
var responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); Console.WriteLine("Response: " + responseData);

the same API is working and giving 200 responses in Ready API tool. - how exactly same is it? same url? same request json? same request method?

Azure DevOps has provided the .NET client libraries for use in .NET code. You can consider using it in your code.

I tried Logging the response and the response looks like : Response: StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:{} @codeninja.sj

@PekoMiko Yes I am logging url, Json body, method(patch) and headers from the code and copying same data and using it in ready API tool and i am getting the proper 200 response with response data.

I think you logged the entire response object. Try logging just response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() Refer to my previous code snippet for how to log the API response.

Below is a sample of my C# code to call the same REST API, and it can work fine. You can reference it to write your C# code.
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Net.Http.Json;
using System.Text.Json;

. . .

var httpUri = "The complete HTTP Uri";
var reqMethod = "PATCH";
var reqPwd = "Personal Access Token";

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
    Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
        string.Format("{0}:{1}", "", reqPwd))));

var data = new[] {
    new {
        id = 12,
        results = new { outcome = 2 }
    }
};

HttpRequestMessage reqMsg = new HttpRequestMessage();
reqMsg.Method = new HttpMethod(reqMethod);
reqMsg.RequestUri = new Uri(httpUri);
reqMsg.Content = JsonContent.Create(data);

var reponse = client.SendAsync(reqMsg);
reponse.Wait();

var jsonOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true };
var jsonStr = JsonSerializer.Serialize(reponse.Result, jsonOptions);
Console.WriteLine(jsonStr);


thank you for your answer. unfortunately, this also dint work and still getting 400 Bad request. is it something related to headers?? or query params?.

@AnitDhanapal We really need to see the request/response headers from ReadyAPI. Its impossible to know why it isn't working if we can't see an example of a request where it does work. Otherwise we will just be making random guesses.

@AnitDhanapal, Show your code when reference my above sample, and as @Jeff B mentioned, show how you call the REST API using ReadyAPI.

The header was the culprit here. Instead of passing headers separately I have passed the headers in this way and it worked.
request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json;api-version=6.1-preview.2;excludeUrls=true;enumsAsNumbers=true;msDateFormat=true;noArrayWrap=true");


Glad that the problem can be resolved, and thanks for sharing your solution. Maybe, you can this answer by yourself. It could be also helpful for other people who are looking for a solution of the similar issues. @AnitDhanapal

I forget if you can do it now, but you should mark this answer as correct. I am glad you found the issue though!
